# How to add <label> <input> & <span> inside a <li> in a specific order

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.add');
var remove = document.querySelector('.draggable');

function dragStart(e) {
  this.style.opacity = '0.4';
  dragSrcEl = this;
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
};

function dragEnter(e) {
  this.classList.add('over');
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.classList.remove('over');
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
  return false;
}

function dragDrop(e) {
  if (dragSrcEl != this) {
    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
  }
  return false;
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  var listItens = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
  [].forEach.call(listItens, function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('over');
  });
  this.style.opacity = '1';
}

function addEventsDragAndDrop(el) {
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart, false);
  el.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter, false);
  el.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver, false);
  el.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave, false);
  el.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop, false);
  el.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd, false);
}

var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
[].forEach.call(listItems, function(item) {
  addEventsDragAndDrop(item);
});

function addNewItem() {
  var newItem = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  if (newItem != '') {
    document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var attr = document.createAttribute('draggable');
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    li.className = 'draggable';
    attr.value = 'true';
    li.setAttributeNode(attr);
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.className = 'container';
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'checkmark' >
      label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(label);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    addEventsDragAndDrop(li);
  }
}

document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    addNewItem();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fdfaf6;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.toggle {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
}

.toggle-button {
  margin: auto 0;
}

.checkmark-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4%;
  transform: translate(-4%, 60%);
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container-circle {
  display: block;
}

.main-box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.list {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.list .input {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: black;
  width: 95%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  text-indent: 4rem;
}

.list span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 1.8;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms;
  color: black;
  will-change: transform;
}

.list span:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

ul .draggable {
  will-change: transform;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: #212121;
  line-height: 3.0;
  cursor: move;
  transition: all 200ms;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d3db;
}

body ul .draggable:after {
  content: url(images/icon-cross.svg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.5rem;
  top: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.48, 0.72, 0.62, 1.5);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

body ul .draggable:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0);
}

.over {
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}


/*checkbox*/

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 4.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 4%;
  transform: translate(-4%, -50%);
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 1.5rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a gradient */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #57ddff 0%, #c058f3 100%);
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 7.2px;
  top: 8px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url(images/icon-check.svg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Todo app</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="toggle">

  </div>
  <div class="list">
    </span><label class="checkmark-circle"><span class=></label>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Create a new todo..." />
  </div>
  <div class="main-box">
    <ul>

      <li class="draggable" draggable="true"><label class="container">NodeJS<input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Good day,

I've been trying to make a dynamic draggable list with a customized checkbox. However, I am unable to prepend/append the span, label and input tags in the exact order I need them, in order to achieve the desired look. I've tried using append & prepend method and document fragment but can't seem to make it work. Here's a copy of my codes:

```
<div class="main-box">
  <ul>
 
  </ul>


function addNewItem() {
  var newItem = document.querySelector('.input').value;
  if (newItem != '') {
    document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var attr = document.createAttribute('draggable');
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    li.className = 'draggable';
    attr.value = 'true';
    li.setAttributeNode(attr);
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.className = 'container';
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.className = 'checkmark'>
    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(label);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    addEventsDragAndDrop(li);
  }
}
```

My desired output should be like this:

`<li class="draggable" draggable="true"><label class="container">User Input<input type="checkbox"><span class="checkmark"></span></label></li>`

PS: I have decided to remove my "not working codes", the codes above would only return the value of the "input" as list.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P33rI.png)

Comment: So what is happening differently than expected? Doesn't appear you have tried creating a checkbox or span or label

Comment: Your desired output is not valid HTML. You have two unclosed `<span>`. Same for the `<label>`.

Comment: "*I have decided to remove my "not working codes"*" - please don't. We cannot help you if we cannot see what's wrong with your code. The `addNewItem` you posted is obviously incomplete, it doesn't create any labels, inputs or spans.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have edited my post and added the declaration of var for label and span. I am unable to figure out the correct syntax to appendChild them to <li>.

Comment: @Chyd Just `label.appendChild(textNode); label.appendChild(input); label.appendChild(span);`, and `li.appendChild(label);`

Comment: @Bergi Thanks man, however, the checkbox is not visible. Everything else fits, the spacing the font. Just the checkbox is not showing

Comment: @Chyd The code you posted doesn't yet create an input element, I assume you added that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the code you are using that does not work. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` on the editor toolbar) to make it runnable here on Stack Overflow so that everyone can see what's going on. Include the functions, and also how those functions are called.

Comment: @Bergi I've edited my post and added the create input element. I've also attached a photo. I have added the desired code output directly on the index.html for illustration.

Comment: `span.className = "checkmark" >` results in the class getting set to `"true"`, so the CSS you have doesn't get applied. Removed the greater than symbol and it works fine. You could also use `span.classList.add("checkmark");` which might be less amenable to that type of typo.

Comment: Also, your HTML is very malformed, with a closing `</span>` starting out the contents of a `<div>`, an unquoted empty `class` attribute, a `label` element without a `for` attribute not wrapping its labeled element, which means it is invalid, and an extra closing `</div>`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey this "checkmark" > typo was culprit. LOL. Thanks everyone for helping out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you give the label a 'for' attribute with the value of the associated tick box's id, the box gets ticked when the label is clicked.
You don't want to nest the span inside the label.
Append the children to the list item in the order you wish them to appear, left to right.
If this still doesn't help you, I suggest your problem might be more CSS related.

```
   function addNewItem()
   {
    var newItem=document.querySelector('.input').value;
    if(newItem!='')
    {
     document.querySelector('.input').value='';
     var li=document.createElement('li');
     var attr=document.createAttribute('draggable');
     var ul=document.querySelector('ul');
     li.className='draggable';
     attr.value='true';
     li.setAttributeNode(attr);
     var label=document.createElement('label');
     label.className='container';

     label.setAttribute('for','tik_'+newItem);

     var input=document.createElement('input');
     input.setAttribute('type','checkbox');
     input.id='tik_'+newItem;
     var span=document.createElement('span');
     span.className='checkmark';
     label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));

     li.appendChild(input);
     li.appendChild(label);
     li.appendChild(span);

     ul.appendChild(li);
     addEventsDragAndDrop(li);
    }
   }
   addNewItem();
```